# How do I use a Liquibase changelog which is in jar file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, liquibase

I currently have the following in my `application.properties`:

`liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`

The actual path to the file is `src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`.

The changelog is found by Liquibase and everything is working as I would expect.

I've moved the changelog and all of the project's JPA entities and repositories into a separate project so that they can be shared with other projects.

This second project is a Maven dependency of the first project. What path do I need to use in `application.properties` of the first project to access the liquibase changelog in the second project?

**Update**

I have:

projectA.jar -> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

projectA.jar -> application.properties

`liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`

projectB.jar -> src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

But I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
```

Comment: The same one. If the jar is in the classpath, and you haven't changed the package of the changelog file, then everything should work fine.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I don't see how it can know that the path is in the 2nd jar file.

Comment: I get the following error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)`

Comment: @JBNizet this works fine when I run the tests in IntelliJ but fails when I run the tests outside of IntelliJ. Assuming a classpath issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm an idiot. My local `~/.m2` repository had an old version of the `jar` without the Liquibase changelog. A `mvn clean install` fixed the issue.